# Memorize twitter data response in nodejs

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm doing a web application that after posting some tweets it return informations like number of retweets etc.
The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to store the data returned by the twitter api.

The twitter function to load the data from the API is:

```
 exports.loadTwit = function(){
     return function(req,res,next){
       let responseDataObject = [];
       req.twitter.forEach(function(entry) {
       T.get('statuses/show/'+entry.id,loaded);
       });

    async function loaded(error, data, response){
     if (error) {
         console.log(error);
     }else{
     dati = await data;
     responseDataObject.push(dati);
     console.log(responseDataObject);  // shows the data
   }
   }
   console.log(responseDataObject);  // shows []
   res.render('db',{dati: responseDataObject});
 }
 }
```

I want to store the data in the responseDataObject. I've put the async/await because I think it's asyncronous so I have to wait for the data.
The problem, showed in the comments, is that inside the loaded function I can see the content of responseDataObject, outside it gives me an empty array.
I don't know how to solve it, any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You've put `res.render('db',{dati: responseDataObject});` outside the async function so the render happens way before the data is actually loaded (asynchronously).

Comment: The problem is that I can render only once, so I want to render when all the data from the forEach is loaded, If I do that, doesn't it render for every foreach?